# Model for selecting bounding box of interest

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am using the [EAST](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03155) text detection model to find text boxes in an image. In all of these images I am only interested in a certain text box that has always has similar pattern (e.g. 5 digits) but varies in its position in the image.

I feed these text boxes into an OCR to get the actual string.

Now, I would like to train a model to which I feed in data consisting of multiple bounding boxes and there corresponding translations from the OCR. I can't figure out what type of classification this is. It should return the index of the bounding box I want, but this index can vary because a data sample can contain different number of bounding boxes and their order varies too.

Answer (score 0):

You can predict coordinates of top left and bottom right corners of your box of interest.
It is better to predict normalized coordinates between 0 and 1.